# System i: system name = unknown?

Tags: sql, configuration, ibm-midrange, db2-400

I'm retrieving the name of some IBM System i from SQL with

```
; select local_host_name from qsys2.tcpip_info
```

This works for several machines, giving me in the first characters the same value than DSPNETA.

But with one machine, the result is "UNKNOWN" (and this is not the good name!)
What could be the problem with this machine?

Answer (score 1):

There's simply no TCP/IP host name assigned...

A bit strange, especially now-a-days, but computers only care about the IP Address.

Ask the admins to assign it via the Change TCP/IP Domain (CHGTCPDMN)  command

**EDIT**
I suspect you've got a name assigned in a DNS server somewhere, so your PC clients haven't noticed.

Comment: At least Apache and some other Software indeed do care for the hostname to (e. g.) enable correct vhost functions or binding only to certain IP addresses.

Comment: Sure you can make software that cares...DNS on the IBM i for instance...but in general host names are for people.

Comment: The SQL is launched from the IBM i itself, so I don't think there is something related to DNS.
Option 10 of CFGTCP doesn't seems to be bad, with the machine's name assigned to its IP address...

Comment: what does option 12 of CFGTCP show?   That is the CHGTCPDMN domain command that Charles mentions. Type CHGTCPDMN and press F4.

Comment: Option 10 of CHGTCP shows the Host Table Entries: Host name, Internet adress... The Host name is correct there. I can't use CHGTCPDMN (*IOSYSCFG authority required)

Comment: @FredericP then talk to somebody who can.  The host table doesn't actually "assign" the host name to the system.  CHGTCPDMN does.